# how to get default video control of native video player in lwuit?

Tags: video, lwuit, mmapi

Below is the code that I have used to play video in native video player. But I am not getting any default control like stop, pause, play.

What I am missing over here? If my code is wrong then what is the right code for that?

```
vc = VideoComponent.createVideoPeer("http://localhost/test.mp4"); 
vc.setFullScreen(true);
player = (Player) vc.getNativePeer();
player.realize();
addComponent(vc);
vc.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you are supposed to call vc.stop() etc. to perform the operations of the video control. I think there is a method getInternal() (or getNative I don't quite remember since we removed this class in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/)) to gain access to the native control.

Comment: but to call vc.stop() i have to add pause/stop button so that if user clicks on button then onactionlistener() i can call vc.stop().

Comment: That's missing on the old VideoControl. It works much better in Codename One.